# Are these two versions of Brouwer fixed-point theorem equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

**Theorem 1:** Any continuous map $g:\mathbf{I}^n\rightarrow \mathbf{I}^n$ has a fixed point, where $\mathbf{I}^n=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n):x_i\in[0,1],\forall 1\leq i\leq n\}$.

**Theorem 2:** Any continuous map $g:\mathbf{D}^n\rightarrow\mathbf{D}^n$ has a fixed point, where $\mathbf{D}^n=\{(x_1,\dots,x_n):\sum_{i=1}^n {x_i}^2\leq1\}$.

**Question:** I believe that I can derive one of these theorems from the other. But I don't have a clear idea about how to do it. Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: All you need to do is fix a homeomorphism $I^n\to D^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf{I}^n$ and $\mathbf{D}^n$ are homeomorphic and the fixed point property is a topological property. E.g. If $h: \mathbf{I}^n \to \mathbf{D}^n$ is a homeomorphism and $f$ is a map on $\mathbf{I}^n$, then $h \circ f \circ h^{-1}$ is a map on $\mathbf{D}^n$ etc..